# AutoFill in input type ="text" in jsp without form tag (JSP)

Tags: html, css, jsp

I added an autofill in my text field but it's not working. Autocomplete attribute is undefined. I don't want to use form action. Also, I added easy-autocomplete.min.css, but still, autocomplete is not working.

```
<input type ="text" id="number" name ="number" placeholder="Please Enter Registered Number" autocomplete="on" class="form-control" value="" onkeypress="return validateNumeric(event)"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right on track. You can use the autocomplete feature of HTML without nesting the input element inside a form.

You just need to change autocomplete="off" to `autocomplete="tel"` and the browser will start to show autocomplete.
"tel" notifies the browser that it is a telephone field and the browser will suggest from a list of saved telephone numbers.

For a list of supported values for autocomplete see this [MDN Article on Autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values).

```
<input type ="text" id="number" name ="number" placeholder="Please Enter Registered Number" autocomplete="tel" class="form-control" value="" onkeypress="return validateNumeric(event)">
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/j63psutL/).